# Is the following differential equation related to some familiar special functions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions, eigenfunctions, sturm-liouville

I've been dealing with some problem and faced a necessity to obtain the eigenproblem for the following second-order differential operator
\begin{equation}
H = x(Ax-g)\frac{d^2}{dx^2} + x(A(1-2j) + B) \frac{d}{dx} + 2gjx + j(Aj-B),
\end{equation}
where $A,B,G$ - some real constants, and $j\in \mathbb{N}$.

The eigenproblem reads
$$
H \psi = E \psi,
$$
which can be rewritten (assuming $x \neq 0, g$) in the form of a second-order differential equation
$$
\psi'' + \frac{\alpha}{x-\sigma} \psi' + \frac{\beta x + \gamma}{x(x-\sigma)} \psi  = 0,
$$
where I denoted
$$
\sigma = g/A, \quad \alpha = (1-2j) + B/A, \quad \beta = 2gj/A, \quad \gamma = j(j-B/A) - E/A.
$$

I am not very deep into special functions. So, before looking for the solution in the form of a series or generalised series, I would like to ask a question here.

Could you tell me please if this equation is related or equivalent to some known one?

Comment: **So, before looking for the solution in the form of a series or generalised series, I would like to ask a question here**  You do all this math and have no access to Maple or Mathematica to check? Just type it and you'll see the solution in terms of HeunC special functions given by Maple.

Comment: @Nasser I tried Mathematics first of all, but it didn't help. But now I see that it's a confluent Heun function indeed. Thank you!

Comment: Here's a PDF with a nice list of classical Sturm-Liouville equations: https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.79.5015&rep=rep1&type=pdf